# How to Add/Remove New Server behind Haproxy with Minimal Disruption

Tags: linux, iptables, load-balancing, tcp, haproxy

Haproxy is currently balancing the load between 2 servers, `A` an `B`. Clients are connecting to these servers via persistent TCP connections.

**Question:** We want to upgrade from server `A` to a more powerful server `C`. How can we add a 3rd server `C` and remove `A` without disrupting/disconnecting the client? If `iptables` is used to redirect connections from `A` to `C`, will it still work if we shut down `A` at some point, or is `A` required to stay online to continue redirecting existing clients to `C`?

Answer (score 0):

haproxy supports a reload operation. Just add all the servers needed in the config file, reload haproxy and then you can also use the enable/disable commands in a stats socket to dynamically enable/disable servers.

Comment: In the config file, server `A` was replaced by server `C`. However after reloading haproxy, only a few connections appear on server `C`, and most clients are still connected to server `A`. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes. There are now two `haproxy` processes. The old process won't terminate before all sessions are terminated, including those to server `A`. Just wait, then `A` should be safe to decomission.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation for this reload operation, and provide an example of what args to provide to ensure zero downtime? For example I'm fairly sure that using `-st` will kill connections while `-sf` will gracefully wait for them to complete.